# normalize the strings in Elixir/Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to normalize the Unicode(UTF-8) strings posted from users thru a `<form>`. Is there any library which treats those things in Elixir(or in  Phoenix or in Erlang)? I'm used to do it in Python like following, but I don't know Elixir has those libraries.

```
import unicodedata
import zenhan
import jctconv

def normalize(strings, unistr = 'NFKC')
    norm = unicodedata.normalize(unistr, strings)
    zenhan = zenhan.z2h(norm, mode=2)
    katahira = jctconv.kata2hira(zenhan)

    return katahira
```

Comment: At last I've written the library by myself, by the way. 
 https://hex.pm/packages/japanese_zenhan

Comment: What you specifically want with your library (converting between half-width and full-width Japanese characters) seems to be not exactly the same as what your question suggests, which is about normalizing UTF-8 characters in a broad sense. The answers below are appropriate for the broad question.

Answer (score 3):

Since Elixir 1.2 there is a [`String.normalize/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/String.html#normalize/2) function. I'm not sure what those python libraries are doing, but this functions is probably a good start for what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If you type `h String.normalize` inside `iex`, you'll get the right information and some examples.

```
Converts all characters in binary to Unicode normalization form 
identified by
form.

Forms

The supported forms are:

  • :nfd - Normalization Form Canonical Decomposition. Characters are
    decomposed by canonical equivalence, and multiple combining characters are
    arranged in a specific order.
  • :nfc - Normalization Form Canonical Composition. Characters are
    decomposed and then recomposed by canonical equivalence.

Examples

┃ iex> String.normalize("yêṩ", :nfd)
┃ "yêṩ"
┃
┃ iex> String.normalize("leña", :nfc)
┃ "leña"
```